# Force the use of a default parameter

Tags: c++, function, default-parameters

"Simple" question, is it possible to explicitly use a default parameter when calling a function which expects one ? Something like :

```
void function(int x, int y = 2, int z = 3)
{
      // prints x, y and z
}

function(10, default, 13); // won't compile of course
// would return x = 10, y = 2 and z = 3
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't you know the default value already?

Comment: @Axalo: Yeah but per _the entire purpose_ of default arguments, it would be better not to repeat them at the callsite.

Comment: I'd second Nathan, this looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Axalo: If I have, to say, a specific lambda function as default parameter, I wouldn't like to write it each time I want to use this default parameter. I was just searching for a more convenient way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with standard C++, but you can look at for example [boost parameter library.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html)

Small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/parameter.hpp>
#include <boost/parameter/preprocessor.hpp>

BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(x)
BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(y)
BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(z)

namespace tag { struct x; }

BOOST_PARAMETER_FUNCTION(
      (void),
      function,
      tag,
      (required (x, (int)))
      (optional
       (y, (int), 2)
       (z, (int), 3)
      )
)
{
   std::cout << "Called with x = " << x << " y = "
   << y << " z = " << z << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   function(1, _z = 5);
   function(1, _y = 8);
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0231e463f5de75c)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in C++ at this time.